# PHP File_put_contents not working

Tags: php, file-permissions, directory-permissions

Check this code:

```
<?php

$url = 'http://www.example.com/downloads/count.txt';

$hit_count = @file_get_contents($url);
$hit_count++;
@file_put_contents($url, $hit_count);

header('Location: wmwc.zip');

?>
```

`@file_get_contents` is working fine and the header location change to the downloaded file also works, but either the hit_count increase or `@file_put_contents` isn't working, because the number with the file doesnt increase by 1. I've set the file permission to 777, but when I try to set the directory permission to 777 also I get a 500 internal server error saying "The server encountered an unexpected condition which prevented it from fulfilling the request."

Comment: Take away the @ and tell us what error you're getting.  @ hides errors.

Comment: You trying to write to an url. i don't think this should work out of the box with `http`. Maybe you meant to write some local file, but then you will have to use a path to that file instead.

Comment: removed the @ and got this: failed to open stream: HTTP wrapper does not support writeable connections in /hermes/bosweb/web046/b462/glo.ckrsavonte/whoolimooli/downloads/index.php on line 7

that was with directory permission 755. 777 produced the same internal server error as before.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**You can't write a remote file via http**.(If you could do that, every one else could change that file also.)

You need to use the local path.

Comment: i'm using wordpress, so the URL doesn't actually point to the root of the system. Since it's php, I'm assuming the path must be relative to the php file executing this function yes, and not the actual URL of the page. Is this correct?

Comment: @CoreyRS It's better to use the absolute path.

Comment: ok then i think you misunderstood my initial post. The URL i set in the variable was the absolute path, the file is hosted on my local server and it still isn't working.

Comment: @CoreyRS I don't mean the http path, I mean the file path in your server, use like `/wwwroot/downloads/count.txt`.

Comment: @CoreyRS Error msg will tell you the reason.

Answer (score 0):

try changing directory properties

```
chown www-data:www-data <dirname>
```

and/or write as follows, if you host on linux

```
<?php
$var ="hi";
shell_exec('echo "'.$var.'">>log.txt');
?>
```