# Writing text to a file on site with php

Tags: php

I am new to PHP and I want to write text to a `.html` file I want to write the data on a URL like as `http://anyurl.com/path/page.html`
the code is following.

```
$file = "http://anyurl.com/path/page.html";
$text = "Hello world";
file_put_contents($file, $text);
```

but it is not working successfully
what am I doing wrong?

Comment: *but it is not working successfully* What does that mean? Do you get any errors?

Comment: no i m not getting any error, but when i open the file where i want to insert data it is still blank.

Comment: try simply `$file="page.html";` PHP is processed on the server and does not need to be prefaced with a web address (http)

Comment: Add error reporting at the top of your file: `<?php
  ini_set("display_errors", 1);
  error_reporting(E_ALL);
 ?>` and then tell us the errors

Comment: "$file" is a variable and not the file. You need to gett he content of that file first. Please check the link for more information "http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php"

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP File\_put\_contents not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12211677/php-file-put-contents-not-working)

Comment: You can't write file using http protocol. It must be file protocol. Use absolute path like /server/file/path. If one can write file using http protocol than i will rewrite files on www.facebook.com

Comment: Read about [FTP](http://php.net/manual/en/book.ftp.php) as alternative to write your file on to another server or use local path for file on same server.

Comment: @Rizier123 i think it is pretty obvious what the error here is. If it was possible to achieve what he is trying to do the internet would be one global Wikipedia.

Comment: @Magic-Mouse Yes that's it! The error is pretty obvious, that's why OP should see it and turn on error reporting

Answer (score 2):

Try this..  it can work properly :)

```
<?php

$myfile = fopen("newfile.html", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");

$txt = "John Doe\n";

fwrite($myfile, $txt);

$txt = "Jane Doe\n";

fwrite($myfile, $txt);

fclose($myfile);
?>
```